# Try to make authenticated HTTPS call via Secure Gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am trying to access a secured WAS URL via the Secure Gateway.  I can access an unsecured page via HTTP. When I set the Secure Gateway Destination to HTTPS and try to access the secured page (requires a userid/password), the connection fails.

Last year I was told that HTTPS was not supported. However, I think that I just don't know how to configure the Secure Gateway to do it now.

Comment: What error do you get exactly? Did you configure client side TLS as described here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/index.html?

Comment: I get the following message:  "This site can't be reached This connection was reset".  I do not understand TLS and why I would set my connection to use that instead of HTTPS.  The link to which you referred showed node.js code that was necessary, but in my case I do not have an application in between my two endpoints, just WAS on one end and someone who wants to use the console via the browser who is outside of the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In order for HTTPS to be in use on both sides of the connection (app to Secure Gateway Server, and Secure Gateway Client to on-premises resource), the protocol should be HTTPS (which it sounds like you have) and you should also enable Destination-side TLS under the Advanced options panel of the destination.  This will cause the connection being made from the Secure Gateway Client to the on-premises resource to be HTTPS rather than HTTP.